# iOS - app crashing for specific controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, breakpoints

I am creating a universal iOS app. I have been doing so for a long time. I have 3 ViewControllers for both iPhone and iPad. Recently, I added few lines of code to iPhone ViewController.m, and the program crashed on `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));` saying `Thread:1 breakpoint:1.1`

I deleted everything I changed, but the crashes occur again. When I launch the app through iPad, everything works fine, since it uses different view controller. If start my app  with different iPhone view controllers, the crash doesn't happen.

I tried commenting my entire code (except the essential parts like @implementation), and it still crashes. I had a backup, so I overwritten both .h and .m files, and it still crashes. I am desperate by now. Only thing I could think of would be to create new project, add all the files there, create new storyboards and paste all my code, which would take a lot of time since I have lot of files. The console shows nothing on the crash except `(lldb)`. I have an exception breakpoint for all exception, yet it catches nothing.

Can you please help me?

Edit: just to let you know, I did try to reset the simulator multiple times, it didn't help though. Both the simulator and my physical iPhone 5s device crashes.

Comment: In the breakpoints view, add a new breakpoint and select "Exception Breakpoints". This will show you exactly where an exception is thrown.

Comment: I do have a breakpoint, it tells me nothing though.
http://i.imgur.com/YmJxQDh.png

Comment: Make sure the breakpoint is set to "On Throw" rather than "On Catch"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have assigned correct classes to your iPhone View Controllers as well as iPad View Controllers.